# Effort Framework does not recognize Entity Model schema

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-5, sap-ase, effort

I have an entity model of a Sybase ASE database and I am trying to use the [Effort Framework](https://effort.codeplex.com/) to create unit tests for it. I am able to access the database with the entity model in both my main project and unit test project, however when try to use Effort to create an in memory database, I get an exception.

Problem Code in Unit Test project

```
public SetUpShims()
{
     string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoPathDataContext"].ConnectionString;
     MyDbContext context;
     // CreateTransient throws exception
     EntityConnection conn = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(connString);

     context = new Data.CoPathDataContext(conn);

}
```

Exception Details: (System.Data.MetadataException)

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
(0,0) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type double.
```

Stack Trace

```
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()  
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) 
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError)  
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)   
at Effort.Internal.Common.MetadataWorkspaceHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(List`1 csdl, List`1 ssdl, List`1 msl)   
at Effort.Internal.Common.MetadataWorkspaceHelper.Rewrite(String metadata, String providerInvariantName, String providerManifestToken) 
at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.<GetEffortCompatibleMetadataWorkspace>b__1(String metadata)
at Effort.Internal.Caching.MetadataWorkspaceStore.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()   
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Effort.Internal.Caching.ConcurrentCache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`1 factory)  
at Effort.Internal.Caching.MetadataWorkspaceStore.GetMetadataWorkspace(String metadata, Func 2 workspaceFactoryMethod)
at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.GetEffortCompatibleMetadataWorkspace(String& entityConnectionString)
at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(String entityConnectionString, IDataLoader dataLoader)
at Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(String entityConnectionString)
```

After looking at the .csdl and .ssdl files that Entity made, I believe I found the fields causing the problem.

SSDL

```
<Property Name="sequence_num" Type="float" Precision="24" Nullable="false" />
```

CSDL

```
<Property Name="sequence_num" Type="Double" Nullable="false" />
```

I tried removing the Precision attribute from the SSDL fields, but but I still received the same error. (Even if it did work, the changes would probably not persist when the model is regenerated )

Anyone thoughts on what is causing the exception and how I should resolve it?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @MiloTheGreat unfortunately no, the only solution we found was to edit the EDMX to remove the column causing the issue and use stored procedures to access the table when we needed the column.

Comment: @MiloTheGreat I've opened a GitHub issue for this that you can follow [here](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/78)

Answer (score 0):

if you have not done so jet upgrade MySQL server to 5.6+ this has been added then update all your date, datetime, time ...... with the with option's 0-6 in ()

Comment: The issue is occuring on a Sybase ASE database and not MySQL